# Алгоритм Евклида (упрощенная версия)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

**Решите задачу одним циклом while**, допускается применение условных операторов.

Наибольшим общим делителем (НОД) двух целых чисел a и b называется наибольший из их общих делителей. Например, для чисел 70 и 105 наибольший общий делитель равен 35.
С давних времен известен следующий алгоритм нахождения наибольшего общего делителя двух неотрицательных целых чисел: пока оба числа строго положительны надо из большего числа вычесть меньшее. Результатом работы (наибольшим общим делителем) является большее число после окончания описанной серии вычитаний или 0, если оба числа в конце равны 0.

Вам заданы целые неотрицательные числа a и b (0≤a,b≤107). Напишите программу, которая **выведет количество вычитаний** при работе такого алгоритма и **результат его работы**.

Входные данные
Единственная строка входных данных содержит записанные через пробел целые числа a, b (0≤a,b≤10 в 7 степени).

Выходные данные
Выведите количество вычитаний в ходе работы алгоритма и результат его работы через пробел.

Пример

входные данные

70 105

выходные данные

3 35

код:

```
a, b=[int(x)for x in input(). split()]
x=0
while a != b:
    if a > b:
        a = a - b
        x=x+1
    else:
        b = b - a
        x=x+1
print(x+1, a)
```

Код не проходит по лимиту времени на 5 тесте.

Comment: *Код не проходит по лимиту времени на 5 тесте.* А оптимизировать кто будет? Нужно `x += a div b` и `a = a mod b`, а на старте цикла менять местами a и b, если a меньше.

Comment: Нужно на питоне, а не на паскале

Comment: Какая разница? Алгоритму пофиг, какой язык. Да и не паскаль это...

Comment: Какой код то получиться с вычитанием и счетчиками то?

Comment: уже сама решила

Comment: но все равно спасибо